# Is there any method in Mongodb that hides after transactions complete?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I've created a simple multi-vendor ecommerce, but I'm wondering if there is any method or technique I can use to hide a specific item once the transaction is already complete?

Like for example. If the item is already sold, it should be deleted/hide from the productslist  in the front end?

I was thinking making the seller delete the product he sold but it will also affect other document because it's using information.

Like for example . Shoe Cabinet is sold, it means that it should disappear to product list but still existing in the database so in the order table, it's still there.

[image]

**EDIT**

So if we apply it in real life, once the item is sold, it should not be appearing in the web page right? so I'm having a trouble what method should i do, because all of my documents are connected to one each other. So if the seller decide to delete the product. The admin as well as the seller dashboard because it's  data gets deleted, is there anyway , or method should I use in mongodb.. I'm wondering if there is a hide function wherein the seller has the ability to hide the products but not delete id.

**EDIT AGAIN**

So I have an idea, I don't if this is a good approach, what if I create another request wherein it will get all order transaction related to that product, and then create a filter method.

```
if product is already existing in order transaction, 
    then don't show it to website.
```